Should userdata connected components be client components in NextJS?
Should all components in NextJS that display user data be client components?

Story: I was working on an auth form for my website that used server action on submit. In it I was making a request to my backend auth provider that used jwt cookies as a way to keep users authenticated. At first the problem was that the cookie was not being assigned to the client. I fixed it. But now, I just can't use that cookie in other server actions or server components. I wanted to make most of my website server-side rendered, but now I don't know if it's possible or not.

I NEVER made an app that used authentication before and I just don't know how to work with it. Should I create a context provider that stores user data? Can I pass a context value to a server component? Should I fetch user-data only on client side with useEffect? Should I rewrite my form to not use server actions and work on client only?
I'd be really grateful if anyone could explain such complex topic for me.

This question is too broad, unfocused, and open ended for Stackoverflow. Next.js has extensive authz documentation. Authentication works perfectly fine with server side rendering. If you're asking how to use the data from the cookie in server components, you should ask a focused question that includes the code, and say exactly what's not working.
